# Is there a way to read csv as dictionary and add some fields to the output?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the sample csv file:

```
name,subject_1,subject_2,subject_3,subject_4,subject_5
Artus Syne,43,71,55,16,51
Evey Reburn,49,7,53,50,63
Giff Wickmann,63,37,21,87,9
Garrot Casetta,22,3,91,75,52
Roselle Maes,71,90,96,79,48
Torin Ziehms,71,31,83,1,25
Jaye Etock,92,9,2,78,55
Thomasina Tinkham,25,78,46,46,90
Adolphus Biernat,91,96,98,94,100
Rex Aspinell,34,75,51,38,99
```

I need output similar to this using dictionaries:

```
{
    'Artus Syne': {'marks': [43.0, 71.0, 55.0, 16.0, 51.0]},
    'Evey Reburn': {'marks': [49.0, 7.0, 53.0, 50.0, 63.0]},
    'Giff Wickmann': {'marks': [63.0, 37.0, 21.0, 87.0, 9.0]},
    'Garrot Casetta': {'marks': [22.0, 3.0, 91.0, 75.0, 52.0]},
    'Roselle Maes': {'marks': [71.0, 90.0, 96.0, 79.0, 48.0]},
    'Torin Ziehms': {'marks': [71.0, 31.0, 83.0, 1.0, 25.0]},
    'Jaye Etock': {'marks': [92.0, 9.0, 2.0, 78.0, 55.0]},
    'Thomasina Tinkham': {'marks': [25.0, 78.0, 46.0, 46.0, 90.0]},
    'Adolphus Biernat': {'marks': [91.0, 96.0, 98.0, 94.0, 100.0]},
    'Rex Aspinell': {'marks': [34.0, 75.0, 51.0, 38.0, 99.0]}
}
```

`dict_reader = {rows[0]:[rows[1],rows[2],rows[3],rows[4],rows[5]] for rows in reader}`

Shows the following output:

```
{'Artus Syne': ['43', '71', '55', '16', '51'], 'Evey Reburn': ['49', '7', '53', '50', '63'], 'Giff Wickmann': ['63', '37', '21', '87', '9'], 'Garrot Casetta': ['22', '3', '91', '75', '52'], 'Roselle Maes': ['71', '90', '96', '79', '48'], 'Torin Ziehms': ['71', '31', '83', '1', '25'], 'Jaye Etock': ['92', '9', '2', '78', '55'], 'Thomasina Tinkham': ['25', '78', '46', '46', '90'], 'Adolphus Biernat': ['91', '96', '98', '94', '100'], 'Rex Aspinell': ['34', '75', '51', '38', '99']}
```

How can I add `'marks'` between the output of key and value pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict_reader = {rows[0]:{"marks": [rows[1],rows[2],rows[3],rows[4],rows[5]]} for rows in reader} # ??
```

The line adds "marks" between your key and list of values.

Comment: See [What comment should I add to code-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: Happy now, matey?

Comment: Slightly, but not by much — barely better than "this code answers your question" or the original nothing at.

Answer (score 0):

From truly minimal amount of code you have in your question:

```
dict_reader = {rows[0]:[rows[1],rows[2],rows[3],rows[4],rows[5]] for rows in reader}
```

You've obviously at least heard of, and are somewhat familiar with [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) — but you're just not taking full advantage of the flexibility they allow with respect to rearranging & reformatting the data being iterated (i.e. rows data from the CSV file in this case) — as long as you follow the basic pattern of `key: value` pairing is followed (and don't allow the code to get so complex it's no longer readable).

Forunately that's the case here, so in the code below the first element (student's name) becomes a key in a sub-dictionary composed of the hardcoded key `"marks"` key whose value is a list of all the remaining row elements (reference via a ["slice"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object `row[1:]`).

Besides requiring less code and executing faster than specifying each the other items individually, using a `slice` makes the code is more generic and independent on exactly how many grades there are following the name on each row — so it won't fail or need to be changed if the number of them changes in the future.

```
import csv

filepath = 'grades.csv'

with open(filepath, 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row.
    rows = {row[0]: {'marks': row[1:]} for row in reader}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(rows, sort_dicts=False)
```